# JDBC SQL Server login failed for user '', Login success in pymssql

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL Server from my Spring Boot App.

I have the login credentials inside application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXXXXX;databaseName=ABC;integratedSecurity=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasoruce.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

It gives the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId:212427fc-5a34-4b59-944a-cdd3856116e5
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    ....
```

But if I try to connect from SQL Server Management using the exact same login credentials(SQL Server Authentication) it works perfectly.

It even works with pymssql. My python code is

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host="XXXXXXXXX", user="user", password="pass", database="ABC")
```

I ran a couple of SELECT statements in python and they worked fine.

I don't understand why I am unable to connect through Java.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was a typo in application.properties

Changed

```
spring.datasoruce.password=pass
```

to

```
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Very silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same method to connect without any problem.

use the following dependency and sees if it works for you

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
</dependency>
```